# Pyqt5 acces GUI elements from subclass

Tags: python, subclass, pyqt5

Need a help to read and write to GUI elements from subclass.
The code:

```
UI element:
[] doABC 

# main.py
import mySubclass

class myAppController(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(myAppController, self).__init__()

        # load view
        uifile = 'myApp.ui'
        uic.loadUi(uifile, self)

        # I can access UI elements like that
        self.pb_Verify.clicked.connect(self.slot_verify) # for slot in main.py

        # Calling slot from mySubclass
        self.pb_EliminateVerifErrors.clicked.connect(mySubclass.fixErrors)

# Show Main window
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = myAppController()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# mySubclass.py - separate file
def fixErrors(self):
    # here I want to check state of checkbox
    if doABC.isChecked():
```

The problem is that `self.doABC.isChecked()` is not working in this case.
I have also tried to pass additional parameters with slot call from `main.py` including `self` or `self.doABC` but it is not working in this way. Also trying to access `main.doABC` or `super().doABC` is not an option.

Done a lot of search on google but nothing fit to my case.

My level is beginner in GUI programming so I even do not know hot it suppose to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that mysubclass needs a reference to doABC to check it.

Here is a working example:

main.py file

```
#!python3
# main.py
import mySubclass
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic


class myAppController(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(myAppController, self).__init__()

        # load view
        uifile = 'myApp.ui'
        uic.loadUi(uifile, self)

        # I can access UI elements like that
        # self.pb_Verify.clicked.connect(self.slot_verify) # for slot in main.py

        # Calling slot from mySubclass
        self.pb_EliminateVerifErrors.clicked.connect(self.EliminateErrors)

    def EliminateErrors(self):
        mySubclass.fixErrors(self.doABC)

# Show Main window
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = myAppController()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here I added a class function to be called by the signal and pass a reference to doABC.

mySubclass.py

```
# mySubclass.py - separate file
def fixErrors(doABC):
    # here I want to check state of checkbox
    if doABC.isChecked():
        print("Works!")
```

Here I removed self from the function arguments as it is not a class function.

That's it! You were pretty close!